# Convert variable to its original form in JShell

Tags: java, java-9, jshell

I'm playing with the [JShell](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/222) and trying to convert a variable to its original form. To do that, I reset everything in the REPL using `/r`, then I imported `java.util.*` and created a list:

```
-> import java.util.*;

-> List<String> l = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("a", "b"));
|  Modified variable l of type List<String> with initial value [a, b]
```

Now I'm trying to convert the lists values to upper case, so I'm doing:

```
-> l.replaceAll(String::toUpperCase)

-> l
|  Variable l of type List<String> has value [A, B]
```

Listing the executed source I've typed using `/list` (or `/l`) shows:

```
-> /l

   1 : List<String> l = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("a", "b"));
   2 : l.replaceAll(String::toUpperCase)
   3 : l
```

Now when I try to reset the list to stage **1** (before changing its values), I'm getting the `import` statement:

```
-> /1
import java.util.*;
```

Does anyone know why this happens? I tried the same without the `import` statement, but I'm getting the same result (I assume this is because it's getting imported explicitly).

---

I've just notice that if I write `/l all` I get:

```
-> /l all

s1 : import java.util.*;
s2 : import java.io.*;
s3 : import java.math.*;
s4 : import java.net.*;
s5 : import java.util.concurrent.*;
s6 : import java.util.prefs.*;
s7 : import java.util.regex.*;
s8 : void printf(String format, Object... args) { System.out.printf(format, args); }
 1 : String a = "a";
 2 : a = "b"
```

I don't know why `/1` executes the first `import` statement and not first the string assignment. Also it's really weird that even if `import java.util.*;` is there, `s5` is `import java.util.concurrent.*;` (which is clearly redundant).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**

Looks like the problem was solved in [JDK 9 EA build 107 on 03-01-2016 (#4560)](https://jdk9.java.net/jigsaw/).

---

After hours of digging, I found an explanation. The command:

```
/list all
```

lists *all* executions, including the start-up entries that were **s**ilently and automatically executed *before* the REPL started:

```
s1 : import java.util.*;
s2 : import java.io.*;
s3 : import java.math.*;
s4 : import java.net.*;
s5 : import java.util.concurrent.*;
s6 : import java.util.prefs.*;
s7 : import java.util.regex.*;
s8 : void printf(String format, Object... args) { System.out.printf(format, args); }
 1 : String a = "a";
 2 : a = "b"
```

One solution is using the `/setstart` command and pass it a file that includes the entries you specify. This way you will not have the default imports and the handy print method available for you.

The other solution would be writing `/9` (the state that's right after the last silent entry).

To be honest, I'm not satisfied with neither of the solutions, I hope there will be better one soon.

Comment: /<snippet-id>

Re-executes that snippet.  It does not reset execution to that point.